# In SFMC Mobile Push, How do i send a notification to a specific device from Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

Suppose a contact key has 3 device mapped to it.
Initially I am sending notification to all the 3 devices of the contact key.
But based on the click/open activity of the user on distinct device I want to put a decision split in the journey builder and then trigger different notification to the clicked and unclicked devices.

So I want to send Push notification based on device id and not based on Subscriber/Contact key.

Answer (score 4):

When the user interacts with the the notification you could add a `tag` for the customer and then use an inclusion/exclusion list to filter the send to a specific device with only the tag.